# vertical aligning for \hbox type boxes inside \vtop boxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tex-core, alignment

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etex}

\begin{document}
    \vtop%
    {%
        \valign{%
        \hbox{text}%
        \hbox{long text}%
        \hbox{long long text}%
    }
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am trying to vertical aligning these boxes. as you can see, I got some errors. how can i fix this?

Comment: In `\valign` you have to use at least one `\cr`, everything before it being the preamble that specifies the alignment. The following is a working (minimal) usage example of `\valign`: `\vtop{\valign{#\cr\hbox{text}\cr\hbox{long text}\cr\hbox{long long text}\cr}}`.

Comment: Also note `\valign` can only be used in horizontal mode but you have it in a vbox so forcing a paragraph is that the intention?

Comment: thank you it works very well. what about vertical alignment? how can i do that?

Comment: you should not use the `etex` package in any new document it is just a legacy package for very old documents using it.

Comment: what do you mean by vertical alignment here? what do you want to align?

Comment: Hi dear David, these boxes are under each other but their centers are not in the same line. I have tried it by \hfill command but this command bring them all to the middle of page and then make them center

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `\halign{\hfil#\hfil\cr text\cr long text\cr long long text\cr}` but at that point you can just use `\begin{tabular}{c}text\\ long text\\ long long text\\\end{tabular}` which is much more user-friendly.

Comment: yes buddy, this is what i was looking for. thanks a lot.

Comment: that is _horizontal_ alignment (moving things left or right), not vertical alignment (moving things up or down). @HenriMenke did well to guess that is what you meant from the information given!